# Ambiguous clause in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a join 4 tables

```
ListingBuyer.joins('left join buyers on listing_buyers.email = buyers.email left join buyer_infos on buyers.id = buyer_infos.buyer_id').joins(:listing).select('listing_buyers.*').where(["email LIKE ?",'%%'])
```

when I run above sql. 
errors =>

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT `listing_buyers`.* FROM `listing_buyers` INNER JOIN `listings` ON `listings`.`id` = `listing_buyers`.`listing_id` left join buyers on listing_buyers.email = buyers.email left join buyer_infos on buyers.id = buyer_infos.buyer_id WHERE (email LIKE '%%')

after, an edit sql command to

```
ListingBuyer.joins('left join buyers on listing_buyers.email = buyers.email left join buyer_infos on buyers.id = buyer_infos.buyer_id').joins(:listing).select('listing_buyers.*').where(["listing_buyers.email LIKE ?",'%%'])
```

The code above works ok.

I want to use sql
    .where(["email LIKE ?",'%%'])
don't want use

```
where(["listing_buyers.email LIKE ?",'%%'])
```

How to edit this sql code

```
  ListingBuyer.joins('left join buyers on listing_buyers.email = buyers.email left join buyer_infos on buyers.id = buyer_infos.buyer_id').joins(:listing).select('listing_buyers.*')
```

Can use

```
where(["email LIKE ?",'%%'])
```

Pls help me.

Comment: Why do you want to use code from which you know that it doesn't work and why don't you want to use the working code?

Answer (score 0):

sql needs to know which tables email column you want to compare to -- if you want it compare to multiple email columns then you'll need to OR them together like

```
where(["listings_buyer.email LIKE ? OR other_table.email LIKE ?",'%%','%%'])
```